# CCCrypt working with pieces of files AES CBC: garbage to end of files on encryption-decryption cycle

Tags: ios, swift, aes, encryption-symmetric

Although I was able to get data encryption and decryption (AES128CBC) working easily with CCCrypt based on some of the great examples of Zaph and others here, I have had two strange problems with CCCrypt when working with encrypting/decrypting files.

1) Upon encrypting and then decrypting a file, I am getting extra garbage at the end of my files, and it is different depending on the file. A hex dump of one original file and the result after an encryption and decryption had and extra "0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B" another file had an extra "05 05 05 05 05" at the end.  A diff at the command line for both resultant files reports "No newline at end of file".  Other than these problems (and problems working with the files relating to these problems like NSJSONSerialization refusing to parse) everything appears to be working.  What is causing this frustrating problem?

2) In order to eventually accommodate very large files I have broken up files into chunks and then used the last 16bytes of the previous chunk to as the IV for the next (since this is the way CBC works anyway, right?). Strangely, on chunks divisible by the key size, using kCCOption PKCS7Padding is causing problems. So that the IV ends up not being the same when decrypting as encrypting between these chunks. When I just set the options to zero for all the chunks including the last which is likely not to be divisible by the key size, I get an exception.  Can anyone help me understand what this issue is? I just use a condition to avoid the issue, but I don't understand the exception, and perhaps it relates to question 1.

```
    let fileSize = getFileSizeFromPath(filePath)
    println("filesize = \(fileSize)")
    while file != nil {
        if let inputBuffer = file?.readDataOfLength(oneMegaByte) {
            if inputBuffer.length == 0 {
                file?.closeFile()
                break
            } else {
                println("input buffer length: \(inputBuffer.length)")
                if let outputBuffer = inputBuffer.AES128CBC(key: key, iv: iv, encryptionOp: encrypt) {
                    println("output buffer length: \(outputBuffer.length)")
                    outFile?.writeData(outputBuffer)
                    println("input file offset:\(file!.offsetInFile) output file offset:\(outFile!.offsetInFile)")
                    if encrypt {
                        let range = NSMakeRange((outputBuffer.length - const.keyLength), const.keyLength)
                        iv = outputBuffer.subdataWithRange(range)
                        println("range of iv for next chunk:\(range), iv value: \(iv)")
                    } else {
                        let range = NSMakeRange((inputBuffer.length - const.keyLength), const.keyLength)
                        iv = inputBuffer.subdataWithRange(range)
                        println("range of iv for next chunk:\(range), iv value: \(iv)")
                    }
                } else {
                    file?.closeFile()
                    println("problem encrypting data")
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            file?.closeFile()
            break
        }
```

And the method I've added to an NSData extension to encrypt and decrypt:

```
func AES128CBC(#key: NSData, iv: NSData, encryptionOp: Bool) -> NSData? {
    if key.length != 16 || iv.length != 16 || key.bytes == iv.bytes {
        return nil
    }

    let data = self
    let dataLength = UInt(data.length)
    let cPtrToData = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
    let cPtrToIVData = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(iv.bytes)
    let cPtrTokeyData = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(key.bytes)
    let keySize = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)

    let buffer: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    if buffer == nil { return nil }
    var cPtrTobuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(buffer.mutableBytes)
    let bufferSize = size_t(buffer.length)

    var operation: CCOperation
    if encryptionOp {
        operation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
    } else {
        operation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
    }

    let algoritm: CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
    var options: CCOptions
    if dataLength % UInt(const.keyLength) != 0 {
        options = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
    } else {
        options = 0
    }
        var encryptedByteCount: UInt = 0

    var operationResult = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, cPtrTokeyData, keySize, cPtrToIVData, cPtrToData, dataLength, cPtrTobuffer, bufferSize, &encryptedByteCount)

    if UInt32(operationResult) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        println("encrypted / decrypted byte count: \(encryptedByteCount)")
        buffer.length = Int(encryptedByteCount)
        return buffer
    }
    println("Error: \(operationResult)")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The following is incorrect: "on chunks divisible by the key size", it is based on block size which is 16-bytes for AES regards of key size.

Comment: Thanks..  I should set change that in case I eventually move to 256bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra bytes are the [PKCS#7 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). Encryption is block based so bytes must be added on encryption and later removed on decryption to achieve this. Per PKCS#7 the extra bytes are the number of bytes added. These additional bytes: "05 05 05 05 05" indicate 5 bytes of padding were added.

If PKCS#7 padding is specified and the input data is an exact multiple of the block size another block is added (and will be all padding bytes). This must be sent of there will be padding errors on decryption. If you know on both encryption and decryption that the data is a multiple of the block size you can skip PKCS#7 padding. In the OP's case this could be skipped on all encryption segments except the last if the intermediate segments were all a multiple of block size. AES uses 128-bit (16-byte) blocks.

Comment: Thank you.  I was pretty sure it related to the padding, but isn't CCCrypt supposed to remove the padding when it decrypts?  Should I be attempting to remove it manually before I close the file upon decryption?

Comment: CCCrypt does not remove the padding on decryption when the kCCOptionPKCS7Padding option is supplied, it is removed after decryption by the statement: `buffer.length = Int(encryptedByteCount)`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  I am using  'buffer.length = Int(encryptedByteCount)' as above but am still finding the extra bytes on the resultant decrypted file.  Perhaps you are saying that I should not use the padding option when decrypting, only encrypting and then that statement will remove the extra padding? I'll give it a try. (Once again thank you)

Comment: How are you seeing/accessing the padding bytes? Are you accessing the data past encryptedByteCount?

Comment: I am looking at the final decrypted file with a hex editor (and comparing it to the original).  The final decrypted file is the result of calling the method that contains the code above (top), which calls the NSData extension method named AES128CBC above.  I call the method once with a Bool set for encryption and then I call it again on the resulting encrypt file with the same key with the Bool set for decryption.  All file names are different.  I have been checking then deleting the 2 produced files before each rerun.  The final decrypted plaintext file contains the padding every time.

Comment: You can not add padding based on the length of the data because at decrypt time there is no way to determine if padding exists. This is a common error. The only case where padding is optional (non needed) is if both sides know a priori that there is no padding through means other than the data. For example if **always** only one one block is encrypted and both sides do not specify padding.

Comment: **Here is the error:**  `if dataLength % UInt(const.keyLength) != 0 {
        options = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
    } else {
        options = 0
    }` because on decryption the length will **always** be a multiple of the block size and the `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` option will not be set. This is because on encryption the data is extended to a multiple of the block size by the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Zaph I have understood the above issues.  For clarity I will answer the above questions more directly.

1) As Zaph said the extra bytes on my decrypted files were padding. They were showing up because of the following offending code, which I have removed.

```
var options: CCOptions
if dataLength % UInt(const.keyLength) != 0 {
    options = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
} else {
    options = 0
}
```

Since the output of CCCrypt will always be divisible by the key length if the PKCS7Padding option is chosen (that's why they are added), the above code would test for a condition that could never be met during a decryption operation. CCCrypt would then not strip the padding back off for me. Since in my application I was mostly handling sub pieces of a file that were always a fixed multiple of the key size and not entire files, I was trying to remove the unecessary padding between files using the above code not considering the ramifications in a decryption operation. This of course is more appropriately done in the code that calls my NSData extension.

2) As per the man page (there isn't one for ios but an old mac one from 2007 can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCCrypt.3cc.html

"if padding is disabled, or when decrypting, the total number of bytes [has] to be aligned to the block size; otherwise CCCryptFinal() will return kCCAlignmentError."

This means that when I set options to zero (didn't set the PKCS7Padding option), the last block would cause the program to crash.

Since I was breaking the file up into sub pieces for my encryption and decryption operation (to eventually accommodate for very large file sizes) I needed to use the last 16 bytes of the previous file chunk as the IV for the next chunk (this is how CBC works, by seeding each subsequent key sized block with an IV generated from the last 16 bytes of the previous block (irregardless of whether 128bit or 256bit key size is used as pointed out by Zaph above).

However, what I failed to understand is that CCCrypt ALWAYS provides padding when encrypting if the PKCSPadding option is chosen, even when the data operated on is a multiple of the key size. CCCrypt was adding 16 bytes to the end of every chunk of the file, and then I was writing that padding in the middle of files.  Ooops.

I'm now using the following code to call the encryption/decryption method, and discarding the padding for method calls on data that does not run to the end of the file at this more appropriate level.

```
while file != nil {
    if let inputBuffer = file?.readDataOfLength(fileChunkLength) { 
        if inputBuffer.length == 0 {
            file?.closeFile()
            break 
        } else { 
            println("input buffer length: \(inputBuffer.length)") 
            println("IV passed to aes128:\(iv)") 
            if let outputBuffer = inputBuffer.AES128CBC(key: key, iv: iv, encryptionOp: encrypt) { 
                println("output bufferlength: \(outputBuffer.length)")

                if encrypt && file?.offsetInFile < fileSize {
                    // only write the data, and discard the padding when not at the end of the file
                    outFile?.writeData(outputBuffer.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, fileChunkLength)))
                    println("Bytes written \(fileChunkLength)")
                    // set the iv for the next chunk in encryption ops (no need when file is finished anyway)
                    iv = outputBuffer.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(fileChunkLength - ivLength, ivLength))
                } else {
                    outFile?.writeData(outputBuffer)
                    println("Bytes written \(outputBuffer.length)")
                    // set iv for decryption ops (doesn't matter for encryption ops where file is at end)
                    iv = inputBuffer.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(inputBuffer.length - ivLength, ivLength))
                }
                println("input file offset:\(file!.offsetInFile) output file offset:\(outFile!.offsetInFile)")

            } else {
                file?.closeFile()
                println("problem encrypting data")
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        file?.closeFile()
        break
```

The NSData extension (second code block above, remains unchanged except for the removal of the problem code mentioned)

Comment: Tere is a lot of code just to save 16 bytes of padding. The more code the less secure. As Kent Beck stated: "Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work" but [who is he](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck) and what does he know. ;-) The simplest thing here is to eliminate all the padding conditional code and just use padding every time.

Comment: Thats true, and I have followed your advice.  Maybe, I need to edit if that is not clear above.  Ultimately, I may be able to use CCCryptor and not just the one shot CCCrypt function so that I am not dealing with blocks of a file.  I need to learn more.  As for adding padding within the file, that is not ideal if the file is to be decrypted by a standard AES128 CBC decrypt on another system I can't control.